# What are suggessions for ZK, Hibernate, Spring, {oracle/mysql}

Tags: java, architecture

I want to build an enterprise application that will have very large number of users(100,000/year), I am thinking (not sure yet) to take ZK, Hibernate, Spring with mysql (after achieving first two milestone switch to oracle).

What are your experiences with these technologies?

How it will be good in terms of performance, scalability and maintenance?

Comment: Please define "very large number".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience with ZK, but there's no reason why you couldn't use Spring/Hibernate/MySQL to build an app with that number of users.